# how to show results from script in php on client side (html)

Tags: php, json, get

I have a quick form in HTML , where the user should write a number.I should provide this number to script in PHP using method GET.Results from this scrip should be shown  on client side ( page in html with form) in JSON format. I do not know how to do this.

My code :

```
<?php

    $data=
    array(
    '12345678912'=>array('name'=>'Insurance Company A' , 'number' => '123'),
    '98765432109'=>array('name'=>'Insurance Company B' , 'number' => '312'),
    '80101066666'=>array('name'=>'Insurance Company B' , 'number' => '980'),
    );

    if ($data[$_GET['pesel']]) {
      echo json_encode($data[$_GET['pesel']]);
    }
    else {
      echo 'wrong number';

    }?>



    <html>

    <head> 
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="server.php" method="get">
            <div style="border:solid; width:500 px; height:300 px;">
            <h1>  Write number </h1>

            <input type="text" name="pesel" />
            <input type="submit" value="ok" />
            <div>

<div id="results">

//place to show result in JSON

</div>

        </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Result on server's page  for number 12345678912

{"name":"Insurance Company A","number":"123"}

How can show it  in div id=results  on page ?

Sorry for my english...

Comment: From the question it is not yet clear what you are trying to do. Please edit the question and add more details. Do you send the number by an ajax request or as a form submission? Where do you want to visualize that result?Inside the same form again or on a different page? Please post your html markup, it might help. And: what do you get as actual result with your current solution?

Comment: Most likely what you are look for is this: "how can I create a html page from within php that gets displayed inside a client?" If so: you simply output html which will get sent to the client as the result of a http request from the client. That result can contain computed things like your result.

Answer (score 1):

it is only one php file which is calling itself again.

input.php:

```
<form action="input.php" method="get">
<input type="number" name="number" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<?php 
$num = $_GET['number'];
echo $num
?>
```

i dont know why you want to show it in browser in json format, json format is rather used for transfer purposes and not for displaying.

Comment: It is not my idea to show data in JSON format.I am study so this is my task for subject ( dustributed processing).I think that function get_file_content() should be useful for me, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: +1 for self submitted form, I love them and they can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display `json_encode($data[$_GET['pesel']]);` in `#results`? Just put the code echoing the stuff there instead:

```
<div id="results">
<?php
if ($data[$_GET['pesel']]) {
  echo json_encode($data[$_GET['pesel']]);
}
else {
  echo 'wrong number';
?>
</div>
```

And change the form so that it submits to the same URL you're displaying it on,

```
<form action="" method="get">
    ...
</form>
```

When submitted, the browser will call the same URL with the `GET` parameter from the form. This will execute your PHP code, outputting the results.

<sup>But it's a weird thing you're doing...</sup>